# Trouble getting XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I am trying to read with C#.
I've been able to do get a lot, but I am having trouble with a specific spot.

This is the XML file:

```
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="60" height="40" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" nextobjectid="4" source="test.png">
  <tileset firstgid="1" name="test" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" tilecount="240" columns="24">
    <image source="../test.png" trans="ffaec9" width="388" height="163"/>
  </tileset>
</map>
```

The attributes I am having some difficulties trying to get are all in the `<image>` tag. I need the `source` and the `width`.

I data in the map but not in the image using

```
tileSize = int.Parse(doc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("tilewidth"));
```

How can I get `source` and `width` from `<image>`?

Comment: I added a closing `</map>` tag to your XML to make your XML well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use Linq and `XDocument` & `XElement` to get the values you need:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<my xml/>");
var tileset = xDoc.Element("map").Element("tileset");
var image = tileset.Element("image");

var tileWidth = int.Parse(tileset.Attribute("tilewidth").Value);
var source= image.Attribute("source").Value;
var width = int.Parse(image.Attribute("width").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx). Here are few examples and [online demo](http://rextester.com/GUU54514):

```
string source = doc.SelectSingleNode("/map/tileset/image/@source").Value; // "../test.png"
string width  = doc.SelectSingleNode("//image/@width").Value;             // "388"
string height = doc.SelectSingleNode("//@height[last()]").Value;          // "40"
```